# JDatabaseMySQL::query: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, joomla

JDatabaseMySQL::query: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELET acl_id FROM `jos_core_acl_axo_map` WHERE section_value = 'com_contentmanag' at line 1 SQL=SELET acl_id FROM `jos_core_acl_axo_map` WHERE section_value = 'com_contentmanager' AND value = '46'

Comment: what you are trying to do and what version of joomla you are using, if possible then plz show your query here so that it will be more easy to understand.

Comment: you have a typo SELET

Answer (score 0):

Probably "value" is a MySQL keyword..

use this character to avoid that MySQL recognize the word as a keyword "`"

in your case:

```
SQL=SELECT acl_id FROM jos_core_acl_axo_map WHERE section_value = 'com_contentmanager' AND `value` = '46'
```